Flutter Android on GitHub Actions using Fastlane gives a deprecated error
I have a flutter project, and I'm trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline using Fastlane and GitHub Actions,
Error
[15:00:45]: ▸ > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[15:00:45]: ▸ ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/toggle_switch-0.1.9/lib/toggle_switch.dart:106:29: Error: The getter 'accentTextTheme' isn't defined for the class 'ThemeData'.
[15:00:45]: ▸ - 'ThemeData' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/theme_data.dart' ('/opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.16.7-x64/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart').
[15:00:45]: ▸ Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'accentTextTheme'.
[15:00:45]: ▸ ? Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.bodyText1!.color
[15:00:45]: ▸ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[15:00:56]: ▸ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug FAILED
[15:00:56]: ▸ FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[15:00:56]: ▸ * What went wrong:
[15:00:56]: ▸ Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Process 'command '/opt/hostedtoolcache/flutter/stable-3.16.7-x64/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[15:00:56]: ▸ * Try:
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[15:00:56]: ▸ > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Current setup
FastFile
default_platform(:android)

platform :android do
  desc "Set Gradle Version and Build Number"
  lane :set_full_version do 
        version = flutter_version()

        android_set_version_name(version_name: version['version_name'])

        android_set_version_code(version_code: version['version_code'])
    end

  desc "Deploy a new version to the Google Play"
  lane :deploy do
    set_full_version

    gradle(task: "clean bundle")

    upload_to_play_store(
      aab: "../build/app/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab",
      track: "alpha"
    )
  end
end

GitHub Actions Workflow (excluding the unnecessary steps)
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev

jobs:
  android:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      BUNDLE_PATH: ../../../../.gem
      GRADLE_USER_HOME: ${{ github.workspace }}/.gradle
      FLUTTER_VERSION: '3.16.7'

    steps:
      ...
        
      - name: Setup Flutter
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: ${{ env.FLUTTER_VERSION }}

      - name: Get pub dependencies
        run: |
          flutter --version
          flutter doctor
          flutter clean
          flutter pub get  
     ...

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 3.3
          rubygems: latest
          bundler-cache: false

      - name: Get bundler
        run: |
           gem install bundler -v 2.5.18

      - name: Build and deploy with Fastlane
        run: |
          cd android
          bundle install
          cd fastlane
          bundle exec fastlane deploy

Note:
On my Mac using the same Flutter version "3.16.7" the build completes just fine by both running:
bundle exec fastlane deploy

or,
flutter build app bundle --release

I've tried changing the flutter versions to all the possible versions installed on my machine and I'm almost 40 GitHub Actions builds in at this point. :)

Did you try it on a macOS runner e.g. macos-13?

Receiving a similar error, plus I can't really afford to use macOS as it'll exceed my free tier pretty quick

If this is a public repo, please share its link (include it in your question). Seems like an MCVE would be helpful to debug this.
